# Schema Registry logs are written to /var/messages

Tags: linux, log4j, confluent-schema-registry

I'm facing a problem about GET logs of schema registry. When I check the log4j properties I see it is configured as `log4j.appender.file.File=${schema-registry.log.dir}/schema-registry.log` which is working as intended (log files are located under /confluent-7.0.1/logs/).

My problem is there are also files under /var/log/. It seems that they are recorded in seperate files from week to week.

```
-rw-------  1 root   root      160273230 Jan  2 12:02 messages
-rw-------  1 root   root     1831024355 Dec 18 03:10 messages-20221218
-rw-------  1 root   root      706439179 Dec 25 03:07 messages-20221225
-rw-------  1 root   root     1158507310 Jan  1 03:06 messages-20230101
```

Content of these files are like that:

```
Dec 25 03:15:09 server_name bash: [2022-12-25 03:15:09,995] INFO 192.168.181.21 - kafkauser [25/Dec/2022:00:15:09 +0000] "GET /subjects/TOPIC_NAME-key/versions/latest HTTP/1.1" 200 178 "-" "-" GETsT (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:62)
Dec 25 03:15:10 server_name bash: [2022-12-25 03:15:10,018] INFO 192.168.181.21 - kafkauser [25/Dec/2022:00:15:10 +0000] "GET /subjects/TOPIC_NAME-value/versions/latest HTTP/1.1" 200 2197 "-" "-" GETsT (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:62)
Dec 25 03:15:10 server_name bash: [2022-12-25 03:15:10,078] INFO 192.168.181.20 - kafkauser [25/Dec/2022:00:15:10 +0000] "GET /subjects/TOPIC_NAME-key/versions/latest HTTP/1.1" 200 178 "-" "-" GETsT (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:62)
Dec 25 03:15:10 server_name bash: [2022-12-25 03:15:10,098] INFO 192.168.181.20 - kafkauser [25/Dec/2022:00:15:10 +0000] "GET /subjects/TOPIC_NAME-value/versions/latest HTTP/1.1" 200 2197 "-" "-" GETsT (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests:62)
```

Is this logging happening because of schema registry or is it just part of the Linux system? I mean, is it result of network logging or schema registry logging? Either way, how can I make it stop or configure to be recorded at somewhere else? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have installed Confluent Platform in a way that uses `systemctl`? If so, then yes, `journalctl` will write to `/var/log/messages` via the process's stdout/stderr logs.

You need to disable the ConsoleAppender in the log4j file to stop this.

Comment: thanks! and yes, I installed it that way. what is the difference between stdout and consoleappender? I disabled stdout and it seems loggin to /var/log/messages is decreased remarkably

Comment: They are the same? `ConsoleAppender` writes to stdout/stderr.